# unable to resolve com.wordnik.swagger.client

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have generated swagger code using swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar but the following code is not getting resolved. Kindly let me know which maven repository library/jar should be used?

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.client.ClientResponseReaders.Json4sFormatsReader._
import com.wordnik.swagger.client.RequestWriters.Json4sFormatsWriter._
```

Comment: @Helen yes I have used -l option

Comment: What value of the `-l` option did you use? (E.g. `java`, `jaxrs`, ...)

Comment: @Helen  I just used  generate -l scala option

Comment: Is your issue the same as [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8520)?

Comment: Thanks, able to resolve this by adding the below entries in pom

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-async-httpclient_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below, then you can mark it as solution.